# Traduction de « let somebody know »

Tags: traduction, constructions-causatives

> I will let Pierre know tomorrow.

Quelle est la bonne traduction de cette phrase ? Je crois que *let .. know* devrait être traduit par *faire/laisser savoir*, mais est-ce que ça devrait être

> Je vais faire/laisser Pierre savoir demain.

ou

> Je vais faire/laisser savoir à Pierre demain.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let know" est traduit par « faire savoir », « laisser savoir » ne se dit pas dans ce contexte (ce serait plutôt la formulation allemande me semble-t-il, on l'utilise plutôt pour dire « Je ne te dis pas pour le moment, je te laisse savoir ».

« Je vais faire Pierre savoir » ne se dit pas. « Je vais faire savoir à Pierre demain » est correct. Cependant, la phrase me paraît bizarre sans COD. « Je vais LE faire savoir à Pierre demain » est plus correct, beau et compréhensible.

Comment: Plus « beau » ne convient pas, non seulement parce que la notion de beauté est subjective, mais tout simplement parce que l'expression du complément d'objet est obligatoire dans cette construction en français (au contraire de l'anglais).

Answer (score 2):

*Let* a beaucoup de sens différents. Dans l'expression *let somebody know*, le verbe *let* ne veut pas dire *laisser*, mais plutôt s'arranger pour. On pourrait traduire « Demain, je vais faire en sorte que Pierre sache », mais ce n'est pas du tout idiomatique. En français, *let somebody know* s'exprime en général avec un seul verbe, pas avec une expression composée.

> Je vais le dire à Pierre demain.
>   Je préviendrai Pierre demain.
>   J'informerai Pierre demain.
>   Je mettrai Pierre au courant demain.

Il existe bien une expression « faire savoir quelque chose à quelqu'un » :

> Je le ferai savoir à Pierre demain.

Mais cette expression est plutôt formelle et pas très courante. La bonne traduction dépend du contexte mais « faire savoir » serait rarement mon premier choix.